# Can I reach this place in Superfrog?

Tags: superfrog

I was a bit nostalgic and fired up my WinUAE and played some Superfrog. At the last level of the ice world I found something funny:

[image: funny image]

My question is: Can I get to those goods somehow? I searched for secret doors but no luck. Any ideas? Or is this an easter egg?

Comment: The tag "retro-game-challenge" has so far been used for the Nintendo DS game of that name. In my opinion it is a potential cause of confusion in this question.

Comment: It's probably an easter egg or a teaser. You can't get any further with the pencil blocking your path. 6-4 has something similar near the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a ledge and assert that no, you cannot.  I'm basing this opinion on [this longplay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GQqdGzaARY), which shows the area in question at [1:39:39](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GQqdGzaARY#t=1h39m37s).

The author of that video goes to great lengths to show all the hidden passages, item collects, etc, and seems to indicate, through jumping around the pencil that it is impassable.

It's not proof, but barring the game's developer making a statement to the contrary I don't think we're likely to get any further on this one.