# Is the Lucozade can bonus in Superfrog just a troll?

Tags: superfrog

This is a side question to [Can I reach this place in Superfrog?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49060/can-i-reach-this-place-in-superfrog)

Having played the Team 17 game Superfrog back in the DOS era, I always remembered the odd dead end found in the lower right part of level 5-4.

[image: I think someone forgot to draw the rest of the level here...]

The play area ends in what looks like a joke, an unfinished drawing. Under the reachable path, one can see a  small area with a few bonus including an extra live. No mater what the player can try, there seem to be no way to reach that area.

What seems odd though is the presence of a power-up shaped like a Lucozade can. As some may already know the game was indeed sponsored by Lucozade. The main character got his power by drinking Lucozade in the game intro and Lucozade bottles where used as energy refiles thru the game.

[image: A Lucozade bottle power up]

Yet... I don't remember the Lucozade **CAN** bonus being used anywhere else in the game. Is this really the case? Is that bonus obtainable elsewhere or is it just part of the unreachable area troll?